# Changing the font on a wxPython TextCtrl widget

Tags: python, fonts, wxpython, textctrl

I'd like to set the font of a **wx.TextCtrl** widget to Consolas, or at least another monospaced font. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
font1 = wx.Font(10, wx.MODERN, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, False, u'Consolas')
myTextCtrl.SetFont(font1)
```

Comment: For more information on fonts and how to apply them, check out http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2011/04/28/wxpython-learning-to-use-fonts/